# Not enough space for post score when using a custom font

Tags: bug, android-app

Votes count is split into two strings.

[image: -10 score displayed incorrectly]

Link for question: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565415/176217

List of defaultly installed fonts in my phone:
[image]

The bug does not affect 2 of 6 fonts (independently of font size):

- NewSmartGothic
- Coffee

---

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-D802
- OS Version: 5.0.2 (152331922a212)

Comment: What question? Did you refresh?

Comment: @ShadowWizard link added

Comment: No repro. Looks like your font is really huge, probably some local setting on your device. (so anything that depends on fixed width will break.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard font size is minimal. But font family is matter. I'm using "purewhite"

Comment: Well, custom font might indeed break design of application which depends on fixed size. I doubt SE can, or should, fix that. They can't possibly test the app for every possible font.

Comment: @ShadowWizard as I see changing font family affect only for tags and votes, not for message body, title or comments. I.e. developers can easily fix this issue.